# Proof verification : $\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x): x>c\}$ for increasing $f$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, monotone-functions

**The Problem :** $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval. Let $f : J \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Let $c \in J$ such that $c$ is not the right-end point of $J$ $($i.e. $c < \sup(J))$. To show that
$$\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x): x \in J; x>c\}$$
Where $\lim_{x\to c^+}f$ represents the one-sided right-hand limit, which is clarified at the start of my solution.

**I'm attaching my solution. Please notify if there's any gap/flaws in the arguments, also whether it could be made shorter by any other technique. Any comment/suggestion regarding this proof, or maybe in general context (style of proof-writing etc), would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

**My Solution :** Let $\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)=l$
i.e. for every $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that
$x \in (c, c+\delta)\cap J \implies l-\epsilon<f(x)<l+\epsilon$

Let $E=\{f(x) : x \in (c, \infty) \cap J \}$ and $E_{\delta}=\{f(x) : x \in (c, c+\delta) \cap J \}.$ We are required to show that $\inf(E)=l.$

Clearly, $E_{\delta} \subseteq E.$ Hence, $\inf(E_{\delta}) \geq \inf(E).$ Now suppose $\inf(E_{\delta}) > \inf(E).$ We wish to contradict this statement.

Let $y_1 \in E_{\delta}, ~y_2 \in E \setminus E_{\delta}.$ Then $\exists x_1 \in (c,c+\delta) \cap J$ such that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $\exists x_2 \in [c+\delta, \infty) \cap J$ such that $f(x_2)=y_2$. Since $x_1 < x_2,$ and $f$ is increasing, we must have $y_1 \leq y_2.$ Note that $y_1 \in E_{\delta}$ and $y_2 \in E \setminus E_{\delta}$ is chosen arbitrarily. Hence any element of $E_{\delta}$ is less than or equal to any element of $E \setminus E_{\delta}.$

Let $\alpha = \frac{\inf(E_{\delta})-\inf(E)}{2}.$ Then $\inf(E)+\alpha$ is not a lower bound of $E$. Hence $\exists x \in (c,\infty) \cap J$ such that $f(x)=\inf(E)+\alpha.$

Now, $\inf(E)+\alpha < \inf(E_{\delta}) \Leftrightarrow f(x) < \inf(E_{\delta}) \Rightarrow f(x) \notin E_{\delta} \Rightarrow x \notin (c,c+\delta) \cap J$.

$[$The last step is the contrapositive of the following statement : $x \in (c,c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow f(x) \in E_{\delta},$ which is true by the definition of $E_{\delta}]$

Hence we must have $x \in [c+\delta, \infty) \cap J$. Let $z \in (c,c+\delta) \cap J$. Clearly $x>z,$ and since $f$ is increasing, $f(x) \geq f(z).$ Again, $z \in (c,c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow f(z) \in E_{\delta},$ and hence $\inf(E_{\delta}) \leq f(z).$ Coupled with the fact that $f(x) < \inf(E_{\delta}),$ we have $f(x)<f(z).$ A contradiction. Hence we must have $\inf(E_{\delta}) = \inf(E).$ Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we have

$$\inf(E_{\delta(\epsilon)}) = \inf(E)\quad\forall~ \epsilon > 0\tag{1}$$

We know that $x \in (c, c+\delta)\cap J \Rightarrow l-\epsilon<f(x)<l+\epsilon$. Then from the definition of $E_{\delta},$ $l-\epsilon \leq \inf(E_{\delta}) < l+\epsilon.$ Hence, by $(1), l-\epsilon \leq \inf(E) < l+\epsilon.$ Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\inf(E)=l$ (since otherwise, we can choose $\epsilon = \frac{|\inf(E)-l|}{2}$ and obtain a contradiction), which is what we set out to prove.

Comment: Looks correct, but you think so much axiomatically. Think as simple as possible then you can solve this problem in just 3 lines..

Comment: it seems correct. But I think you must clear the last sentence, that is $$\inf(E)\in[L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon),\forall \epsilon>0\implies\inf(E)=L$$ I mean: you wrote a long proof very detailed in all the steps except this last one.

Comment: @ForgotALot Thanks a lot (both for the edit and the suggested alternative proof)

Comment: @Ashkan That's a problem I'm facing, all my proofs are long due to this line of thinking. I predominantly rely on basic axioms and definitions than trying to come up with some trick. Any suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: @Dragon you are doing all very detailed and axiomatic because you need to prove yourself. This is fine. When you dont need to prove yourself you will write shorter proofs.

Comment: @Masacroso I'm editing on the last sentence that you mentioned. I'm not completely sure about what you mean by that I need to prove myself. But it's true that, when I do mathematics, I feel this extreme need of going into details and clarify each and every step, possibly more than needed. Is it a good habit to keep or it can potentially be irritating for people who review my work? On the other hand, I do want to expand my arsenal and learn tricks about how to solve problems quickly.

Comment: @Dragon its fine. When you will had a lot of proofs done then new proofs will rely in other theorems that you had proved before, so probably you wont repeat many things and the next proofs get shorter. For the last sentence consider $$\inf(E)\in[L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon),\forall\epsilon>0\implies\inf(E)\in\bigcap_{\epsilon\in\Bbb R_{>0}}[L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$$

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks a lot, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x,y \in J$ such that $c < x < y$  we have $\inf(E) \le f(x)\leq f(y)$, Since $f$ is increasing.

Now by letting $x \rightarrow c^+$ in each sides of the inequality (while $y$ is fixed), we get $\inf(E) \leq l\leq f(y)$ for all $c<y \in J.  $ Hence by taking infimum over $y: ~c<y$  from each side of the later inequality we get   $\inf(E) \leq l \leq \inf(E)$.

**Edit**
In case if the existence of $l$ is questionable:

Let  $l_1 =\liminf_{x \to c^+}  f(x)$ and $ l_2 =\limsup_{x \to c^+}  f(x)$ then observe that $$\inf(E) \leq l_1 \leq l_2 \leq f(y).$$

for all $c < y$. Now take infimumu over all $y$ such that $c<y.$ Done

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to prove only that _if_ the limit exists, then it is equal to $\;\inf\{f(x): x \in J; x>c\}\;$, and not that that limit actually exists. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster  you are right.  looking at Op solution I assumed he knows the existence of limit , since he/she called it by $l$. however the proof is valid by considering limsup and liminf instead of $l$ .

Comment: Could you perhaps update the answer with the details? Because I don't see exactly how that would work...  Thanks!

Comment: @MarnixKlooster  Done

Answer (score 0):

Let $c<x_n <\sup (J)$, $n=1,2, \dots$ such that $x_n\downarrow c$.

Note that $f[c,x_1]\supset f[c,x_2]\supset \dots \supset \lim_{n\to\infty}f[c, x_n]=A \dots (1)$.

Since $f(x)$ increasing function, $\sup\{f[c,x_1]\}\geq \sup\{f[c,x_2]\}\geq \dots \geq \sup \{A\}$. But $\sup \{A\} =\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x>c\}(*)$. On the other hand $\sup \{A\}= \lim_{x\rightarrow c^+} f(x)$

To prove (*), note that, (Assuming $A$ is non-empty):Note that,$\sup \{A\}\leq\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x>c\}$ trivial since we can always choose $M\in \mathbb{N}$ for which $x_*\geq x_M>c$ such that $\sup f[c,x_M]\leq \inf E(x_*)$ for every $x_*>c$ where $E(x_*)=\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x\geq x_* >c\}$, that gives us $\sup \{A \} \leq \inf\{ E(x_*)\}$ for all $x_*>c$ for $(1)$.

On the other hand Let $x_1>y>\sup \{A\}$, implies $\exists N$, such that $f(x_N)<y<f(x_{N+1})$, then y can not be $\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x>c\}$.Then $\sup \{A\}\geq\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x>c\}$ Again let $z<\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x>c\}$, then $z$ can not be equal to $\sup \{A\}$. Then $\sup \{A\}\geq\inf \{f(x):x\in J;x>c\}$. Hence $(*)$ holds.